# Spring DATA JPA Between and IsBetween keywords

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How to get Spring DATA JPA method (like `findBy`....) for the query below:

```
Select * from USER where '2016-02-15' between VALID_FROM and VALID_TO;
```

Comment: what is '2016-02-15? what are the names of your columns?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should do it in this way

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE e.REFERENCE_FIELD BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

Your code is not very clear, and I dont know what is 2016-02-15, if is the name of your field or is a value, if is a value and you are using between, you must specify a range, and a field to be compared.

EDIT

If you want to use spring data jpa then do it like this

```
findReferenceFieldBetween(value1,value2);
```

check the ref. [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

Comment: Hi @jpganz18 , I meant JPA method by name... like findByAandB()... I was already able to write it using native query.          
                      
And yes "2016-02-15" is a date value which I need to check if it exists between two Date columns range in my table.

Comment: findByReferecefieldBetween(A, B);

Answer (score 6):

In Spring boot: 2.1.6, you can use like below:

```
List<OrderSummaryEntity> findByCreateTimestampBetween(String fromDate, String toDate);
```

Just to confirm how it is working internally, If you put  `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` property in applocation.properties file, you may see the query like below. Internally nothing but BETWEEN query only.

```
Hibernate: select order0_.order_id as order_id1_8_, 
           order0_.create_timestamp as create_t2_8_, 
           order0_.inventory_at_order as inventor3_8_,
           order0_.last_updated_by as last_upd4_8_,
           order0_.location_id as location5_8_, 
               ...
               ...
               ...
          from order_summary order0_ 
          where order0_.create_timestamp between ? and ?
```

Comment: Nice tip about the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true`. The `between` comparison is inclusive, according to: http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/hibernate/hibernate-hql-between-expression/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include both boundary dates in result you can use below in Spring data jpa

```
@Query(value = "{'field' : {$gte : ?0, $lte : ?1}}", fields="{ 'field' : 1}")

List<DTO> findByFieldBetweenQuery(String first, String second);
```

Remove fields section if all fields are expected. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: That does not look remotely like a JPA query. Are you sure this works? `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` doesn't even have a property called `fields`.

Comment: You are using `fields` as a parameter to the `@Query` annotation: `fields="{ 'field' : 1}"`. That's not a parameter that `@Query` has. 
Also, the queries must be JPQL queries: these are JSON objects. This code will not compile, let alone run.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN 'fromDate' AND 'toDate';
```

You also can use the below JPA method to get data as the above query.

```
findByTimeStampGreaterThanEqualAndTimeStampLessThanEqual(fromDate,toDate);
```